# Python mock requests.post to throw exception

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, python-requests

Using Python 3.5, requests==2.18.4, Flask==0.12.2, urllib3==1.22

I have a method `some_method` in my main `server.py` file, that is supposed to make a `POST` to some url with some data:

```
def some_method(url, data):
    ...
    error = None
    try:
        response = requests.post(url, json=data)
    except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError as e:
        ...
        app.logger.error(...)
        response = None
        error = str(e)
    return error, response
```

The server file defines: `app = Flask(__name__)`, and `some_method` is called from `@app.route(... methods=['PATCH'])`.
If this method throws an error, the route will eventually return a `500`.

Tests are run from a test file importing the app with `import server` and `app = server.app`, using `unittest`, and importing `mock.patch`.

I am able to test the overall app behavior, with a test that shows that the app route behave as expected when the method returns an error and seeing that the route terminates at the right spot:

```
class ServerTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    ...
    @patch('server.some_method')
    def test_route_response_status_500_when_throws(self, mock_response):
        mock_response.return_value = 'some_error_string', None
        response = self.app.patch(some_url, some_data, content_type='application/json')
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 500)
```

However, I would really like to have another test to test `some_method` in isolation:

1. Mock `requests.post` to throw `requests.exceptions.ConnectionError`
2. Show that the method logs an error (I know I can mock my `app.logger` and assert that it logged during the execution)

Comment: So where did you get stuck? You can mock `requests.post` just fine, and you can have a mock raise exceptions by setting the `side_effects` attribute.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Mock the `requests.post` function, and on the mock set the [`side_effect` attribute](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.side_effect) to the desired exception:

```
@patch('requests.post')
def test_request_post_exception(self, post_mock):
    post_mock.side_effect = requests.exceptions.ConnectionError()
    # run your test, code calling `requests.post()` will trigger the exception.
```

From the linked documentation:

> This can either be a function to be called when the mock is called, an iterable **or an exception (class or instance) to be raised.**
>
> [...]
>
> An example of a mock that raises an exception (to test exception handling of an API):
>
> ```
> >>> mock = Mock()
> >>> mock.side_effect = Exception('Boom!')
> >>> mock()
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   ...
> Exception: Boom!
> ```

(Bold emphasis mine).

This is also covered in the [*Quick Guide* section](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#quick-guide):

> `side_effect` allows you to perform side effects, including raising an exception when a mock is called:
>
> ```
> >>> mock = Mock(side_effect=KeyError('foo'))
> >>> mock()
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>  ...
> KeyError: 'foo'
> ```

Comment: Thank you! I was doing what you mentioned in your response, but I had a few errors:
1. `requests.exceptions.ConnectionError` -> `requests.exceptions.ConnectionError()`
2. Was trying many variations of `patch`, also object but then changed to  -> `@patch('requests.post')`